# Return XML From Web Api

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I've done hours of reading on this and tried many different solutions I've found on SO and else where and still haven't been able to get this working.

The situation is, I've written a web api rest service to provide an interface to a 3rd party application via COM.  It's been in production now for a number of months and works flawless.  I've been tasked by a new consumer to provide XML responses, up until now it's been working exclusively with JSON perfectly fine.
No matter what I try I can not get an XML response using Postman for testing.
In Post man I have both the content-type and accept header tags set to "application/xml"

So my controller is pretty simple

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/getobject")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetByGSTNumber(string token, string key)
    {
        DataConnection connection = null; new DataConnection();//Set up COM reference
        DataObject dataObj = null;
        try
        {
            connection = new DataConnection();
            connection.login(token);
            dataObj = new DataObject(connection);
            Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dataObj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null) { Request.RegisterForDispose(connection); }
            if (dataObj != null) { Request.RegisterForDispose(dataObj); }
        }
    }
}
```

The Definition of my data object, again don't think overly complicated.  It does do a bit of parsing under the hood to convert non CLR types to CLR types.

```
public class DataObject : IDisposable
{
    internal DataConnection dbConnection;
    internal dynamic _dataRecord;
    public string Key
    {
        get { return _dataRecord.KeyField.ToString(); }
    }

    public string Property1
    {
        get { return _dataRecord.Property1Feild.ToString(); }
    }

    public DataObject(DataConnection connection)
    {
        dbConnection = connection;
    }

    public void OpenRecord(string key)
    {
        if (!_dataRecord.Seek(key))
        {
            throw new Exception("Record not found");
        }

    }

    #region IDisposable Support
}
```

So what I've tried so far is change

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dataObj);
//Returns JSON even if specifying XML in request
```

to

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dataObj "application/xml");
// returns <ExceptionMessage>Could not find a formatter matching the media type 'application/xml' that can write an instance of 'DataObject'.</ExceptionMessage>
```

I've decorated my data object with [DataContract] and properties with [DataMember] tags but that resulted in no change.

I've created a parameterless constructor, which got me this, but no properties/values are in the xml

I've tried setting the XML Serializer in my Global.asax file but this had no noticeable effect.
What am I missing?

**Update**
Included application start where I've tried different combos of UseXMLSerializer = true/false with all the above changes

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
        xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
    }
```

I've also tried putting an XML serialize method on my data object and changing my create response call

```
public string XMLSerialize()
    {
        XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataObject));
        using (var sww = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
            {
                xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, this);
                return sww.ToString(); // Your XML
            }
        }
    }
```

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, creditor.XMLSerialize(), "application/xml");

This results in a 
    There was an error generating the XML document.
    System.InvalidOperationException
Exception aside, I'm not 100% sure that this would produce a correctly formatted result

**Update**
Have changed the properties on my business class to have an empty setter and now getting XML with properties in my response.  Visual studio is complaining about empty setters but compiling, I'm guessing it's not the norm.

```
    public string Key
    {
        get { return _dataRecord.KeyField.ToString(); }
        set {} VS give me a wiggly green line on this but no info
    }
```

Comment: "I've tried setting the XML Serializer in my Global.asax file" -> You mean you've added the formatter? (although it should be there by default unless someone has explicitly removed it)

Comment: Sorry, should of been more specfic.  var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;

Comment: Can you breakpoint the API method and tell us what the `Accept` header is at the point where the API method is triggered?

Comment: See following tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization

Comment: @John  Breakpoint on the Request.CreateResponse line Accept = application/xml

Comment: @jdweng, Thanks but have already read that a few times.  Is there a specific section that I should be looking at again?

Comment: I don't see the following two lines in your code : var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;

Comment: @jdweng  Thanks for the interest.  I had been setting that in my Application_Startup().  Have updated the original question

Comment: What is the inner exception for the "There was an error generating the XML document" error?

Comment: Also, the `XmlSerializer` will ignore `Key` and `Property1` because they don't have setters (but `DataContractSerializer` would not).

Comment: @steve16351 Inner exception is The type DataObject was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.  Guess that was a bit of a clue.  Should of checked that before.  So I need setterers on my properties?  The underlying data I'm accessing is read-only

Comment: In your example you have `new XmlSerializer(typeof(AccredoMasterData))`. Should that not be `new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataObject))`?

Comment: @steve16351 yes, quite correct have updated my code

Comment: Ok, so does it then produce some xml or is there an exception still? If so, is the exception still the same?

Comment: Same error.  It was me doing a copy paste into my question where I fluffed it

Comment: The variable 'xml' is local in the startup so it does nothing for the rest of the code : var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;

Comment: @jdweng  Thanks for trying to help, and yes while you where right in my sample code. It turned out the source of my problem was in the way I've structured my data objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all those that helped.  Thanks a ton.
Credit goes to Steve16351 for giving me the hint that got me going in the right direction.

So the problem was in the way I had defined my DataObject class.  I needed two changes.

Firstly a paramaterless constructor.
Secondly, I needed to specify property setters.  Initially didn't think I needed setters since I would never need to Post data using this class as it's underlying data source is read only.